# Check user in AD group in SSAS Tabular Dax Row Filter

Tags: ssas-tabular

We have Is_Member() function in MS SQL server to  check the current login user in some Windows AD group or SQL group. Is there any equivalent function in SSAS Tabular DAX. I have to put some row filter.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the USERNAME() function.

See documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tutorial-row-level-security-onprem-ssas-tabular

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/username-function-dax

If you are using Custom/Form Authentication you could use the CUSTOMDATA() function which takes a custom parameter passed into a connection string to the SSAS server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/customdata-function-dax

Let me know if this helps.